# Como carregar os dados apartir do item selecionado?

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

**Contexto:**

Como carregar dados a partir de um modelo selecionado? É necessário usar JavaScript? Em caso positivo o código deve está em um arquivo externo ou no mesmo código?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o modelo for selecionado deve ser carregado os itens do modelo. Como mostra a imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código em html edita.blade.php:**

```
 <div class="modal fade modal-default" id="modalGerarChecklist" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Gerar Checklists</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-18">
                             <input type="hidden" id="idProjeto" name="idProjeto" value="{{$projeto->id}}">
                             <label class="control-label">Modelos</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="idModelo" name="idModelo"  required>
                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                @foreach($checklistsModelos as $checklistModelo)
                                    <option value="{{$checklistModelo->id}}" {{old('checklistModelo') == $checklistModelo->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$checklistModelo->modelo}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select> 
                            <br/>
                           <label class="control-label">Itens</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="comboItens" name="comboItens"  multiple='multiple' disabled>
                            </select> 

                         </div>


                        </div><!--Fim do modal-body-->

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <center>
                            <a id="btnGerarChecklist" type="button" class="btn btn-primary gerarChecklist" data-dismiss="modal"  align="center" style="width: 300px; height: 40px">Gerar</a>
                        </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <!--Fim do modal de Gerar Checklist-->
```

```
  <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js')}}"></script> 


   <script>

     $(function(){

         jQuery("#idModelo").change(function(){

            var idModelo = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery.getJSON("/projetos/comboItens/"+idModelo,function(data){
               jQuery.each(data, function(key, value){
                   alert(jQuery("#comboItens").append("<option value="+value.id+">"${value.descricao_item}"<option/>"));

               });
            });

            //jQuery("#comboItens").attr("disabled",false);


         });

     });

   </script>
```

**Método comboItens do Controlador ProjetoController.php**

```
 public function comboItens($id)
      {
        $checklistEstrutura = DB::table('checklist_estrutura')
        ->join('checklist_modelo', 'checklist_modelo.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.modelo_id')
        ->join('checklist_itens', 'checklist_itens.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.itens_id')
        ->select('checklist_itens.id', 'checklist_itens.descricao_item')
        ->where('modelo_id','=', $id)
        ->groupBy('checklist_estrutura.estrutura_id', 'checklist_itens.descricao_item')
        ->distinct()
        ->get(); 

         $checklistEstruturaArray = (array)  array_values($checklistEstrutura->toArray()) ; 

        $checklistEstruturaModelo =  ChecklistEstrutura::where('modelo_id', '=', $id)->first();

        //é necessário retornar um response em json


       return response()->json($checklistEstruturaModelo);

      }
```

**Rotas web.php**

```
$this->group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' =>'admin','prefix'=>'projetos'], function(){

    $this->get('comboItens/{id}', 'ProjetoController@comboItens')->name('projeto.comboItens');

   //Final das Rotas de gerenciar projetos
});
```

**Estrutura de banco de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode fazer em js, já o conteúdo não necessariamente precisa ficar no html, se você ta usando PHP, aspnet por exemplo dai você pode fazer um conteúdo dinâmico com conexão ao banco de dados. Mas esse exemplo que eu fiz é só pra você ver como que faz em js, existe outras formas de fazer. LINk
https://jsfiddle.net/2d0ouxkv/1/